# In R, after naming columns with vectors from a list, how to find a matching column name (grep and match give integer(0), NA)?

Tags: r, match

I am probably missing something very simple.  I have a list of vectors, that I then use as column names.  Now I want to be able to find which column (index) for a given vector.  I have tried grep and match and for some reason I am getting NA and integer(0) when I know it's the very first column as I see from just viewing my dataframe.  What am I doing wrong?  Code below:

```
#Loops to create S
S <- list()
i <- 1

for(a in 0:12){
  for(b in 0:(12-a)){
    for(c in 0:(12-a-b)){
      for(d in 0:(12-a-b-c)){
        e <- 12 - a - b - c - d
        S[[i]] <- c(a, b, c, d, e)
        i <- i + 1    
      }
    }
  }
}

P <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(S), ncol = length(S))
for(i in 1:length(S)){
  for(j in 1:length(S)){
    
    #lots of stuff
    
  }
}

#Rename P matrix cols/rows
colnames(P) <- S
rownames(P) <- S

#Now I want to find which column has the name "c(0,0,0,0,12)" -- should be first one.  I tried:
grep("c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12)", colnames(P))
match('c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12)', names(P))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't your column names be more meaningful than `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12)` ?

Comment: They represent certain things so it makes meaning for my context but I didn't want to explain all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your `match` attempt is you used `names(P)`, and `names()` is not defined for matrices. Use `colnames` or `rownames` and it will work as expected:

```
match("c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12)", colnames(P))
# [1] 1

match("c(1, 5, 4, 0, 2)", colnames(P))
# [1] 758
```

Your `grep` attempt doesn't work because `()` are special characters in regex. You can use `grep` if you escape your parentheses or set `fixed = TRUE`, but you shouldn't really use `grep` for exact whole string matches - `match` or `==` or `%in%` are better tools. Save `grep` for when you need partial matches or pattern matching through regular expressions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! and thanks for explaining the grep as well, I appreciate it!